# Trying to track down the Firefox Gnome Integration addon from Ubuntu 10.4ish

Tags: firefox, mate, platform-integration, palemoon

I'm currently using the Pale Moon browser with the Mate DE. Integration isn't perfect, so I thought about using an old default Firefox extension to see if that would fix the few issues. Since Mate is very similar to Gnome 2 and Pale Moon is very similar to Firefox from the Gnome 2 era, I thought it has a good chance of fixing the few minor issues I'm having. I'm having a hard time finding this file separate from the system ISO.

TL;DR, anyone have an old copy of the gnome-integration Firefox addon from Ubuntu 10.04 or thereabouts? Thanks.

Comment: "Pale Moon" - this sounds like it's not Ubuntu, and Mint is not Ubuntu either.

Comment: It relates to Ubuntu and not Pale Moon or Mint because what I'm asking for is a file from an old version of Ubuntu. 

I just provided context for my specific use-case to maybe help others with a similar issue, and to discourage "why do you want something that old?" comments.

Comment: The oldest *supported* release of Ubuntu on this site is currently Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reaches the end of it's *standard support* life five years after release; with it's release in 2018-April (thus 18.04) it'll reach EOSS in 2023-April.  Older releases whether or not they are LTS are EOL & off-topic on this site.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site. Your stated OS (10.04) is years past it's EOSS & EOL. Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

The `firefox-gnome-support` package is likely what you're after. You'll probably find them here http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox-3.5/

But there's also links on Launchpad here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/11.0+build1-0ubuntu4

Comment: Thanks! I can't find that .xpi file in either of those directories. The only ones I can find are for testing purposes. It looks like I would need to build Firefox from that source to access that addon. Any other ideas?